# Wordpress and WooCommerce, too many widgets

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce on a friend's Wordpress site. She does use a custom theme and WooCommerce does not seem to like it a lot. The main problem is that it shows some additional widgets on the shop and product pages. Twentyten and Twentyeleven do not show the widgets. Any suggestion on how to get rid of them on the custom theme? Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to Wordpress, so I hope it's not too obvious. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the widgets aren't available when you change themes then you are right, they are in the custom template.  They will either be in the functions.php file or in their own separate  file in an includes folder.  That file will be included/required from the functions.php file.

What you are looking for is some code that looks like the following;

There will be a new class defined, extending the `WP_Widget` class, ie

```
class My_widget extends WP_Widget {
  // custom widget code in here
}
```

and then following that there will be a hook which registers this new widget.  You just need to comment out any lines which are hooking into widgets_init.  They will look like the following;

```
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("My Widget");'));
```